# Оценить время генерации матрицы

Tags: время, матрицы, теория

Как можно подсчитать время генерации матрицы к примеру 10х10 на обычном компьютере.
Тобишь 2-4 ядра, 2.8-3.4 ГГц и тд. 
Считал по формуле:

```
O(n*log(n))
10*ln(10)/ln(2)*x
```

Где x, это скорость выполнения одной операции. В случае 3.4ГГц это будет 3.4нс.

Результат вышел:

> 1,13*10^-7 сек.

Верно ли я посчитал или нет?

Comment: вы думаете значение в матрицу прям так одной операцией вписывается? и несколькими ядрами?

Comment: `O(n*log(n))` - как ты с такой асимптотикой собрался матрицу генерировать?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что правильнее всего будет засечь это время на реальной машине используя BenchmarkDotNet для прогрева и вообще подготовки окружения.

Сделать порядка 10 000 измерений и взять среднее время :)

И запускать все на релиз билде.

Может кто что еще добавит к важным нюансам на которые нужно обратить внимание...

PS: не забудь подготовить саму ОСь -- подчистить все лишние проги с автозагрузки и подобное.

PS2: А все теоретические просчеты времени могут разбирся о суровую реальность бытия)

Comment: Я был бы не против посчитать это на реальной машине, но увы, задание стоит именно рассчитать теоретически.

Comment: А Вы рассчитайте теоретически, а потом проверьте Ваши расчеты, измеряя время генерации матрицы на реальной машине. :-)